# Show that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration

I need to show that the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1 , 1]$.

A function is called Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on its domain. The boundedness condition is satisfied. To see the continuity part, the only point which seems to cause problem is $x=0$.Now, I haven't showed that the function is continuous in the entire domain except at $0$ .

Also, I had a second approach in mind. I can write $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \Big[\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}\frac{\sin x}{x} + \int_{\epsilon}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{x} \Big]$$

But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: It is clear that our function is continuous except at $0$, where it is not defined. (The discontinuity is removable, but we do not need that.) And "except at $0$" is definitely almost everywhere. You are proposing to use a powerful *theorem* (it is certainly not a standard *definition* of Riemann integrable). If you already have it, fine. If you do not, you may be expected to use instead the definition of the Riemann integral.

Comment: which theorem are you talking about?

Comment: That a function is Riemann integrable on an interval iff it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: Your second approach does not look like  a good idea.

Comment: It's clearly bounded and also continuous a.e. (except at $0$ but it's measure is also $0$) So is this statement a sufficient condition?

Comment: @ Mathaholic - ok so what is the problem? Is there no way to show that the function is riemann integrable in $[-1, \epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon ,1]$ ?

Comment: The problem as written is ill-posed - the map $x\mapsto \frac{\sin x}x$ is not defined on $[-1,1]$. It is however defined on $[-1,\varepsilon]\cup[\varepsilon,1]$ for any $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, and continuous on a compact domain, hence Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Math 1000  - So I can break the integral limits in two parts and conclude from there that on each interval my function is riemann integrable and hence on the entire interval $[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: No, only that it is Riemann integrable on $[-1,\varepsilon]\cup[\varepsilon,1]$ for any $0<\varepsilon<1$.

Comment: So how do I do it?

Comment: First of all your statement "a function is called Riemann integrable ..." is wrong. The statement is not a definition but rather a deep result about integration. A much simpler approach is to show that a function is integrable even if it has a finite number of discontinuities. See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1757564/72031 And the function $f(x) = (\sin x)/x$ here has just one discontinuity.

Comment: It's not Riemann integrable on [-1,1] because it's not defined on all of [-1,1].

Comment: @zhw Well I am not sure if your statement is right. It is continuous almost everywhere in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Review the definition of Riemann integrability.

Comment: I have read that a function is Riemann integrable iff it is bounded and continuous a.e. on its domain.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin x}x,& x\ne 0\\ 0,&x=0\end{cases}$$ and $f_n:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ by $$f\chi_{\left[-1,-\frac1{n+1}\right]\cup\left[\frac1{n+1},1\right]}. $$ Then $f_n\to f$ a.e. and $|f_n|\leqslant 1$, so by dominated convergence
$$\int f\ \mathsf d m = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int \ f_n\ \mathsf d m = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[ 2 \mathsf{Si}(1) - 2 \mathsf{Si}\left(\frac1{n+1} \right)\right]= 2\mathsf{Si}(1) $$ where $\mathsf{Si}$ denotes the sine integral defined by $$z\mapsto \int_0^z \frac{\sin t}t\ \mathsf dt $$ for $z\geqslant0$.